# Is there any way to call OpenGL code writing by c++ in python via pybind11?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, pybind11

I've writed a toy example using OpenGL and c++

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init(void)
{
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glOrtho(-5, 5, -5, 5, 5, 15);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  gluLookAt(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  return;
}

void display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0, 0);
  glutWireTeapot(3);
  glFlush();
  return;
}

void test()
{
  int argc = 0;
  char **argv=NULL;
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
  glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL 3D View");
  init();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

And then build the code using

```
gcc -o test test.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

It works fine. But I want to call this function in Python,  than I've tried

```
# include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
...

PYBIND11_MODULE(py2cpp, m)
{
  m.doc() = "opengl test";
  m.def("display", &test, "test opengl");
}
```

Build code above using

```
g++ -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -lGL -lGLU -lglut test.cpp -o py2cpp`python3-config --extension-suffix` -I /home/xiaohanbao/anaconda3/envs/ros/include/python3.8
```

I compiled the code successfully. But when I import the library using `import py2cpp`, I got

```
Import Error: /path/py2cpp.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:  undefined symbol: glutInitWindowPosition
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: If I build the code to a library without pybind11, i.e., a .so file, then I can successfully call `test()` using `ctypes` module, but I do want to use pybind11.

Comment: Since you compile with -shared, it seems like the loader doesn't find the relevant GL library when loading your program. Did you try to run `ldd py2cpp[...].so` to see if that's the case?

Comment: @unddoch You're right. It just cannot find library about GL.
`ldd py2cpp.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0514d000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0fe2764000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0fe254c000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0fe215b000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0fe1dbd000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0fe2d52000)`
So what should I do ?